# Security for PHP code on local server

Tags: php

I am deploying my php app on a local server for my customer. I will be using wamp to run the app. How can I secure my php code from reuse?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install zend into your apache and use zend to encode PHP and obfuscate your application to Protect your code.

You can read here too:
http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard